# Using Qt control panel function in OpenCV error NULL pointer

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I tried to google my question in several website but it still no answer.
My problem is look like this http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Runtime-error-for-createTrackbar-in-control-panel-td7550203.html

I tried to create the control panel in OpenCV window using Qt integration as show in an example of OpenCV Document: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html

By this function, it should be separate between image window (with 'imshow()') and control panel (with in other window, called control panel).

However, it is not work when run to the code 'createTrackbar(num1, NULL, &val1 , 255, NULL);' the error message 'Null pointer' is shown. However, if I change the parameter to the window name it is work!.

My code is like this:

```cpp
#include <...opencv.hpp>
#include <...highgui.hpp>

char* num1 = "testTrack";
int val1 = 100;
const string mainwin = "show";

int main() 
{  
        while (true)
        {
            frame = capture();
            createTrackbar(num1, NULL, &val1 , 255, NULL);
            process_frame = image_processing(frame);
            imshow(mainwin, process_frame);

        // [Exit the system]
        if (condition) 
        break;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `createTrackbar` needs a window to be created on, you should give window name to it..

Comment: Hi @guneykayim, but in the document, it seems like we can declare as NULL pointer to window? when we would like 'Trackbar' appears in 'control panel' not on the window.
HERE is something mention about this, http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answer is useful after all this time, but you need to use an empty string instead of a null pointer.

Try with:

```
 createTrackbar(num1, "", &val1 , 255, NULL);
```

Comment: Since this is a long issue, thank you for your answer.